# How can I add a link to a WPForms "contact us" form to the main menu?

Tags: menus, forms, contact

I created a basic WordPress site with a main page and a menu on it. WordPress allowed me to add links to pages. But I cannot find a way to add a link to a form created in WPForms. My goal is to have a link open a full-page contact us form.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine you'll need to create a "form" page and embed the form using a [shortcode or block](https://wpforms.com/docs/creating-first-form/#display-form):

> There are two different ways to embed your forms to a WordPress page: by using the built-in embed wizard through WPForms, or manually, through the Block Editor.

Once you have the page ready - you can test it by viewing it directly - you can add a link to it from the menu.